# How adjust this table with multicolumn in tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

i'm trying to create a rigth table using multicolumns and tabularx. This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXXXX}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{obs}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 30}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 100} \\\cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        && RMSE& $R^2$ & RMSE & $R^2$\\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\\cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        Cluster 1   &44&5.39&0.36 &5.57&0.31\\
        Cluster 2   &17&6.83&0.34&5.69&0.42\\
        Cluster 3   &107&5.58&0.66&6.40&0.21\\
        Pistoia     & 80 &6.44& 0.41&6.44& 0.66\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Validation results for simulated and observed average of R median.}
    \label{tab:results_BNs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

obs should stay over 44

thank you!

Comment: you say obs should be over 44, which is in the second column, so what is the intention  of  `\multicolumn{2}{c}{obs}&`  which centers it over the first two columns, are you just looking for `&obs&`  to put obs in column 2 ?

Comment: as there is no linebreaking here I would not use `tabularx` just use a normal tabular and decimal-align the numeric columns using `siunitx` or `dcolumn` packages.

Comment: @David Carlisle thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the sugestions in  David Carlisle's previous comments, here are two possible versions of your table. To place `obs` as a header to just the second column, I have removed the `\multicolumn{2}` command aound it and added a `&`. Additionally, I have used `siunitx` to align the numbers with respect to the decimal marker and deleted the empty line in the column header.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3]*{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
        \toprule
       & obs &\multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 30}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 100} \\\cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        && {RMSE}& {$R^2$} & {RMSE} & {$R^2$}\\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        Cluster 1   &44&5.39&0.36 &5.57&0.31\\
        Cluster 2   &17&6.83&0.34&5.69&0.42\\
        Cluster 3   &107&5.58&0.66&6.40&0.21\\
        Pistoia     & 80 &6.44& 0.41&6.44& 0.66\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Validation results for simulated and observed average of R median.}
    \label{tab:results_BNs}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3]*{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
        \toprule
       & &\multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 30}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RES 100} \\\cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        &obs & {RMSE}& {$R^2$} & {RMSE} & {$R^2$}\\
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
        Cluster 1   &44&5.39&0.36 &5.57&0.31\\
        Cluster 2   &17&6.83&0.34&5.69&0.42\\
        Cluster 3   &107&5.58&0.66&6.40&0.21\\
        Pistoia     & 80 &6.44& 0.41&6.44& 0.66\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Validation results for simulated and observed average of R median.}
    \label{tab:results_BNs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: really thanks @leandriis